# Multiple UIAlertViews to Enter Data

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have two buttons that will pop up an alertview with textfield to input data. However, only certain characters are allowed in each of the two textfields. Somehow, if I press the second button, the character set from the first button is used. What's going on here?

Also, what would be a more elegant form of inputting data without having to use an alertview? Could I use a modal view? If so, how?

```
- (IBAction)editRate
{
    if(!self.powerOn) return;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit Jail Fee Rate"
                                                    message:@"Enter New Daily Rate"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

    [alert show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
    {

        UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        field.placeholder = @"Enter New Rate";

        NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];

        if ([field.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound)
        {


            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Only numbers are allowed in this field."delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert show];

            FeeRate.text=@"0.00";
        }
        else
        {

            FeeRate.text = field.text;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:field.text forKey:RATE_KEY];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }

    else
    {

    }
}

- (IBAction)editDate
{
    if(!self.powerOn) return;

    UIAlertView *alertDate = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit Jail Fee Date"
                                                    message:@"Enter New Date"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


    alertDate.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [[alertDate textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

    [alertDate show];


}


- (void)alertDate:(UIAlertView *)alertDate clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex2
{
    if (buttonIndex2 != alertDate.cancelButtonIndex)
    {

        UITextField *fieldDate = [alertDate textFieldAtIndex:0];
        fieldDate.placeholder = @"Enter New Date";

        NSCharacterSet * setnew = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789/"] invertedSet];

        if ([fieldDate.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:setnew].location != NSNotFound)
        {


            UIAlertView *errorAlert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Only numbers and slashes are allowed in this field."delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert1 show];

            FeeDate.text=@"00/00/0000";
        }
        else
        {

            FeeDate.text = fieldDate.text;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:fieldDate.text forKey:DATE_KEY];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }

    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ...or… you can use tags; for every alert use different tags alert.tag=1.. and so on. In the delegate method check if (alertView.tag==1)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `UIAlertView` is dismissed then a function called

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

is called.

So, both your alert views call this function.

One way to tell which alertView is calling it, you could create an ivar or better two properties like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *rateAlert;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *dateAlert;
```

and you should initialize like this:

```
[self setRateAlert:[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle...
[self.rateAlert show];
```

and

```
[self setDateAlert:[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle...
[self.dateAlert show];
```

and then:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView==self.rateAlert) {
        //do whatever for rateAlert
    } else {
        //do whatever with dateAlert
    }
}
```